# Library for component graph display with Qt

Tags: library, c++, data-visualization, graphs, component-diagram

I am interested in finding a good c++ library (or base code upon which to create one) to draw interactive connected graph components in Qt.

By **connected graph component**, I mean graphs whose nodes are components with input and output sections in the style of graph nodes in [Blender Node Editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Nodes/Editor) or [Grasshopper](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/page/tutorials-1), see [example](http://modelab.is/download/grasshopper-primer-third-edition-example-files/).

By **interactive**, I mean that I need to be able to access the component position and locations to let the user select and interact with them.

My requirements:

- for Qt in C++
- least amount of external dependencies (best would be just a header library)
- support for automatic layout (or semi-automatic, the nodes being set, the edges having to be connected automatically)
- interactivity-enabled (i.e. not just an image output, most likely based on QGraphicsScene)

My current implementation is using [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) with [QGV](https://code.google.com/p/qgv/) but it only support simple component nodes (no specific input / output elements). While GraphViz supports record and html elements, QGV doesn't and it looks like a sufficient hassle to implement it within a fork of QGV correctly given the constraints from GraphViz that I wonder if there is no better choice, trying to not use GraphViz.

I could also be fine with a simple non-graphics library that does the layout given size constraints and relative position constraints (the component blocks have a fixed size, the input/output nodes positions are fixed given the location of the component block).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe too late but still here is the library I develop for general-purpose node graph editing.

https://github.com/paceholder/nodeeditor

Key Features:

- Based on Qt 5.x with C++14
- Based on `QGraphicsScene`
- Nodes are behaving according to user-defined models
- No dependencies (just Qt).
- Different color styles

Check the video to see what the library is capable of:
[image: 1]

Comment: It is a bit late for me to use it for the project I was planning it for, indeed, but it's worth having it mentioned somewhere. I may look at it if I happen to need it in a new system.
Do you know how well it scales to larger graphs? I'm talking about a few hundreds of nodes, which is quite common for algorithm-based systems. One I found out about later (but in Python is that of Antimony, a Media Lab project for CAD, http://www.mattkeeter.com/projects/antimony/3/), and it seems to scale up to some level.

Comment: In terms of the graph rendering performance it scales pretty well as it is based on the super-fast QGraphicsScene engine. If we talk about signal propagation, I assume it must be a little slower than a Python script (for example). Internally I use `std::shared_ptr` to wrap user's data and to pass it to the next model. This requires some memory allocations and shared pointer copying. Anyway, one guy managed to make a real-time GLSL renderer based on this Node Editor with a dozen of primitives that delivered 30-60 FPS (https://github.com/v0q/CollaborativeResearchProject)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, absolutely stunning! @paceholder